# Получить элементы JSON-строки

Tags: python, json, get

У меня есть определенный GET-Запрос и я не совсем понимаю как именно я могу его разложить, чтобы в дальнейшем с ним работать.

Мне нужно получить *"original"* каждого (или нескольких) скриншотов. Пример json-ответа:

```
[{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.jpg?1538659796"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.jpg?1538659810"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/c556cfa758be73019c3aefbb438a26012b22cf56.png?1538659842","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/c556cfa758be73019c3aefbb438a26012b22cf56.jpg?1538659842"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/8f52db449ddaebaf021bca37ee34fc0ae4a25a96.png?1538659862","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/8f52db449ddaebaf021bca37ee34fc0ae4a25a96.jpg?1538659862"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/9a032b7358d7954b3060ff13e00f81dc8dba7045.png?1538659877","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/9a032b7358d7954b3060ff13e00f81dc8dba7045.jpg?1538659877"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/428a2e54a23eeb6ad85ab653362145667f8d41a5.png?1538659893","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/428a2e54a23eeb6ad85ab653362145667f8d41a5.jpg?1538659893"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/de90b92be4ff5bfa21e1394be777896e2fb6cba3.png?1538659908","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/de90b92be4ff5bfa21e1394be777896e2fb6cba3.jpg?1538659908"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/19a25eeaf1d3541bd9e6b076c3be860a570cb9d2.png?1538659922","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/19a25eeaf1d3541bd9e6b076c3be860a570cb9d2.jpg?1538659922"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/04223ab4638ee8f7ddb93ed7d4fca84a35505fe6.png?1538659945","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/04223ab4638ee8f7ddb93ed7d4fca84a35505fe6.jpg?1538659945"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/b2a7453be4a27dfa30392594cf8383229403331f.png?1538659959","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/b2a7453be4a27dfa30392594cf8383229403331f.jpg?1538659959"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1b7e2a3d0fbcedd0e9bedfbc768c56c113c5f2b9.png?1538660047","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1b7e2a3d0fbcedd0e9bedfbc768c56c113c5f2b9.jpg?1538660047"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/a82080601be779e28a6aa772a6ef09e95c118dab.png?1538660066","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/a82080601be779e28a6aa772a6ef09e95c118dab.jpg?1538660066"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1428a5003c7d1bbbaeb18b5fcde49e0e532a79e2.png?1538660082","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1428a5003c7d1bbbaeb18b5fcde49e0e532a79e2.jpg?1538660082"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1a4d65a5b6824aab54e3d0497414be172c6392bc.png?1538660098","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1a4d65a5b6824aab54e3d0497414be172c6392bc.jpg?1538660098"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/9486f89400a24881a89dd6dd49b68a7088622e46.png?1538660113","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/9486f89400a24881a89dd6dd49b68a7088622e46.jpg?1538660113"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/bd20c3399b7f0fc0ccff9541e7c19bd7aa1389f4.png?1538660138","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/bd20c3399b7f0fc0ccff9541e7c19bd7aa1389f4.jpg?1538660138"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/b5d8e65ba80ef5aa53034d1b51079627d7c726da.png?1538660157","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/b5d8e65ba80ef5aa53034d1b51079627d7c726da.jpg?1538660157"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/c819f6747cb53c3554fecb4add8d5176a57b9fe4.png?1538660192","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/c819f6747cb53c3554fecb4add8d5176a57b9fe4.jpg?1538660192"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1caadfa7c8e4ae4db878b9976a1fed3ddf573f63.png?1538660208","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1caadfa7c8e4ae4db878b9976a1fed3ddf573f63.jpg?1538660208"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/531f24959a6cb851b757d5385fda18f1606115af.png?1538660228","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/531f24959a6cb851b757d5385fda18f1606115af.jpg?1538660228"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/441ff064016a0921988f3654f96c3dceb4aea2c7.png?1538660245","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/441ff064016a0921988f3654f96c3dceb4aea2c7.jpg?1538660245"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/f939767a73e8a6755ec5251f4bb0464f5b7b5441.png?1538660269","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/f939767a73e8a6755ec5251f4bb0464f5b7b5441.jpg?1538660269"}]
```

Буду рад каждому ответу. Также, если вам будет удобнее, то я оставил ссылку на [GET-Запрос](https://shikimori.one/api/animes/37450/screenshots) сайту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы не знаете как распарсить ответ от сервера с помощью Python, то для этого можно использовать библиотеку [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
In [12]: import requests

In [13]: headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

In [14]: resp = requests.get('https://shikimori.one/api/animes/37450/screenshots', headers=headers).json()

In [15]: type(resp)
Out[15]: list
```

Дальше со списком можно работать:

```
In [16]: resp[0]['original']
Out[16]: '/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796'

In [17]: resp[1]['original']
Out[17]: '/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810'
```

Можем с помощью спискового включения получить все значения `original`:

```
In [18]: originals = [i.get('original') for i in resp]

In [19]: originals
Out[19]: 
['/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796',
 '/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810',
 '/system/screenshots/original/c556cfa758be73019c3aefbb438a26012b22cf56.png?1538659842',
 '/system/screenshots/original/8f52db449ddaebaf021bca37ee34fc0ae4a25a96.png?1538659862',
 '/system/screenshots/original/9a032b7358d7954b3060ff13e00f81dc8dba7045.png?1538659877',
 '/system/screenshots/original/428a2e54a23eeb6ad85ab653362145667f8d41a5.png?1538659893',
 '/system/screenshots/original/de90b92be4ff5bfa21e1394be777896e2fb6cba3.png?1538659908',
 '/system/screenshots/original/19a25eeaf1d3541bd9e6b076c3be860a570cb9d2.png?1538659922',
 '/system/screenshots/original/04223ab4638ee8f7ddb93ed7d4fca84a35505fe6.png?1538659945',
 '/system/screenshots/original/b2a7453be4a27dfa30392594cf8383229403331f.png?1538659959',
 '/system/screenshots/original/1b7e2a3d0fbcedd0e9bedfbc768c56c113c5f2b9.png?1538660047',
 '/system/screenshots/original/a82080601be779e28a6aa772a6ef09e95c118dab.png?1538660066',
 '/system/screenshots/original/1428a5003c7d1bbbaeb18b5fcde49e0e532a79e2.png?1538660082',
 '/system/screenshots/original/1a4d65a5b6824aab54e3d0497414be172c6392bc.png?1538660098',
 '/system/screenshots/original/9486f89400a24881a89dd6dd49b68a7088622e46.png?1538660113',
 '/system/screenshots/original/bd20c3399b7f0fc0ccff9541e7c19bd7aa1389f4.png?1538660138',
 '/system/screenshots/original/b5d8e65ba80ef5aa53034d1b51079627d7c726da.png?1538660157',
 '/system/screenshots/original/c819f6747cb53c3554fecb4add8d5176a57b9fe4.png?1538660192',
 '/system/screenshots/original/1caadfa7c8e4ae4db878b9976a1fed3ddf573f63.png?1538660208',
 '/system/screenshots/original/531f24959a6cb851b757d5385fda18f1606115af.png?1538660228',
 '/system/screenshots/original/441ff064016a0921988f3654f96c3dceb4aea2c7.png?1538660245',
 '/system/screenshots/original/f939767a73e8a6755ec5251f4bb0464f5b7b5441.png?1538660269',
 '/system/screenshots/original/8a08330e6357597c9fd5b59d022d4d6617305217.png?1538660300',
 '/system/screenshots/original/98cded3fe400f377ecc3fa9b2122f708ed96225b.png?1538660319',
 '/system/screenshots/original/048e349101e6d1760da8d80a6ea267c4378b1eca.png?1538660332',
 '/system/screenshots/original/522ef730c2a6f67e8284cfaf9a8f089679b6922a.png?1538660353',
 '/system/screenshots/original/ee7ebca54b76514b14a5ffd7547a2d867d14acc8.png?1538660393',
 '/system/screenshots/original/1450f1834c4bfd5ffa7aee387d959d63c8ef1115.png?1538660406',
 '/system/screenshots/original/ed09e981cf6363a8efb19e4014865e159492d481.png?1538660421',
 '/system/screenshots/original/338a0b27a55ff0506dc79f19035ad29e9d7a6a93.png?1538660434',
 '/system/screenshots/original/436a22543f495285a495ac4e2ff0286ae9a9cae9.png?1538660446',
 '/system/screenshots/original/b182358f981b21656838ff9865decb12d2f87b29.png?1538660460',
 '/system/screenshots/original/0daf22251d737808e0d54592d5f9519ed873653d.png?1538660491',
 '/system/screenshots/original/cbd46e9377b854929dd9f1ac02538b2d71d6c60a.png?1538660504',
 '/system/screenshots/original/909720b398958677a147e8d3f7125a8bceace36f.png?1538660543',
 '/system/screenshots/original/dcda2c09cd2483520f15a0309c2a58bc50b5cc2d.png?1538660555',
 '/system/screenshots/original/2eb6dc14f67a187d9fdf2279b44b9d97bbd8d67f.png?1538660573',
 '/system/screenshots/original/9ad3b665e78dbc9f45612b767bcf409acfe3b3ae.png?1538660589',
 '/system/screenshots/original/2cba7ba83a9dde6048ababbaafdfcc2b36e273f0.png?1538660608',
 '/system/screenshots/original/60770dc44e38ca67fb4025316e6b290ca965e941.png?1538660625',
 '/system/screenshots/original/82e1c2aee0cca26120816d6318240cabc65a5e74.png?1538660641',
 '/system/screenshots/original/8e66154668430f292f542f6da11ed601538907e3.png?1538660653',
 '/system/screenshots/original/3d3bd9d15c0dbf7c7649b30208d1284ea37fe3d0.png?1538660667',
 '/system/screenshots/original/45b666be26e8e9a826f17ee608c6696649e2d89a.png?1538660680',
 '/system/screenshots/original/f3ceeea1441a1dd6cce5c3c0efcc6400ac674064.png?1538660694',
 '/system/screenshots/original/b818987daccdf106d12103ff0a04c131ee841f23.png?1538660709',
 '/system/screenshots/original/179b4fbcb203904a1bef9ab4f9c971b1664b047f.png?1538660718',
 '/system/screenshots/original/6b3cf210dde3e0a7a5beb86900b45ccd0d94e671.png?1538660735',
 '/system/screenshots/original/007cb71b9a6436f5c009b9a2dec32bc4224e0291.png?1538660748',
 '/system/screenshots/original/226bb4f4d68d683a900349e08ff797ab6b537ca2.png?1538660760',
 '/system/screenshots/original/0d02ca398a2b4c85a04d8f1dca270914b9be5709.png?1538660773',
 '/system/screenshots/original/956393be44a5d6c04994bc6ad13fd645cfcf959a.png?1538660792',
 '/system/screenshots/original/4313c6f5be2676c42ab774b0daed620aa9efb267.png?1538660805',
 '/system/screenshots/original/b33457047af019fe33ad19bffdfdeb295f1a934e.png?1538660815',
 '/system/screenshots/original/452b5a461813b07401d9cfc49be9ebbc9e51bd60.png?1538660825',
 '/system/screenshots/original/a7a06ecf570279088caad26ccac9254a77925e78.png?1538660836']
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
response = [{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.jpg?1538659796"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.jpg?1538659810"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/c556cfa758be73019c3aefbb438a26012b22cf56.png?1538659842","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/c556cfa758be73019c3aefbb438a26012b22cf56.jpg?1538659842"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/8f52db449ddaebaf021bca37ee34fc0ae4a25a96.png?1538659862","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/8f52db449ddaebaf021bca37ee34fc0ae4a25a96.jpg?1538659862"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/9a032b7358d7954b3060ff13e00f81dc8dba7045.png?1538659877","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/9a032b7358d7954b3060ff13e00f81dc8dba7045.jpg?1538659877"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/428a2e54a23eeb6ad85ab653362145667f8d41a5.png?1538659893","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/428a2e54a23eeb6ad85ab653362145667f8d41a5.jpg?1538659893"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/de90b92be4ff5bfa21e1394be777896e2fb6cba3.png?1538659908","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/de90b92be4ff5bfa21e1394be777896e2fb6cba3.jpg?1538659908"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/19a25eeaf1d3541bd9e6b076c3be860a570cb9d2.png?1538659922","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/19a25eeaf1d3541bd9e6b076c3be860a570cb9d2.jpg?1538659922"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/04223ab4638ee8f7ddb93ed7d4fca84a35505fe6.png?1538659945","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/04223ab4638ee8f7ddb93ed7d4fca84a35505fe6.jpg?1538659945"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/b2a7453be4a27dfa30392594cf8383229403331f.png?1538659959","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/b2a7453be4a27dfa30392594cf8383229403331f.jpg?1538659959"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1b7e2a3d0fbcedd0e9bedfbc768c56c113c5f2b9.png?1538660047","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1b7e2a3d0fbcedd0e9bedfbc768c56c113c5f2b9.jpg?1538660047"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/a82080601be779e28a6aa772a6ef09e95c118dab.png?1538660066","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/a82080601be779e28a6aa772a6ef09e95c118dab.jpg?1538660066"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1428a5003c7d1bbbaeb18b5fcde49e0e532a79e2.png?1538660082","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1428a5003c7d1bbbaeb18b5fcde49e0e532a79e2.jpg?1538660082"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1a4d65a5b6824aab54e3d0497414be172c6392bc.png?1538660098","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1a4d65a5b6824aab54e3d0497414be172c6392bc.jpg?1538660098"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/9486f89400a24881a89dd6dd49b68a7088622e46.png?1538660113","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/9486f89400a24881a89dd6dd49b68a7088622e46.jpg?1538660113"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/bd20c3399b7f0fc0ccff9541e7c19bd7aa1389f4.png?1538660138","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/bd20c3399b7f0fc0ccff9541e7c19bd7aa1389f4.jpg?1538660138"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/b5d8e65ba80ef5aa53034d1b51079627d7c726da.png?1538660157","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/b5d8e65ba80ef5aa53034d1b51079627d7c726da.jpg?1538660157"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/c819f6747cb53c3554fecb4add8d5176a57b9fe4.png?1538660192","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/c819f6747cb53c3554fecb4add8d5176a57b9fe4.jpg?1538660192"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/1caadfa7c8e4ae4db878b9976a1fed3ddf573f63.png?1538660208","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/1caadfa7c8e4ae4db878b9976a1fed3ddf573f63.jpg?1538660208"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/531f24959a6cb851b757d5385fda18f1606115af.png?1538660228","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/531f24959a6cb851b757d5385fda18f1606115af.jpg?1538660228"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/441ff064016a0921988f3654f96c3dceb4aea2c7.png?1538660245","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/441ff064016a0921988f3654f96c3dceb4aea2c7.jpg?1538660245"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/f939767a73e8a6755ec5251f4bb0464f5b7b5441.png?1538660269","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/f939767a73e8a6755ec5251f4bb0464f5b7b5441.jpg?1538660269"}]
for el in response:
   print(el['original'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, прогоняем список с помощью `map()`, вычленяя по ключу через `dict.get(key)` значение элемента словаря.

```
resp = [{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796",
  "preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.jpg?1538659796"},
 {"original":"/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810",
  "preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.jpg?1538659810"},]

filtered = list(map(lambda x: x.get('original', None), resp))
```

Answer (score 0):

В ответах выше есть ряд недосказанностей, попробую восполнить пробелы.

```
import requests


# Спасибо CrazyElf, подсказал, что объект response имеет метод json(), 
# возвращающий ответ в формате json без ручного обращения к библиотеке json

def get_original(url: str) -> list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()
```

Comment: `requests` сам может отдавать `JSON` через `response.json()`, зачем вручную делать `json.loads`?

Comment: да? Впервые слышу. Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: В коде одного из других ответов это даже используется )